# Finding poles and zeros of a circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, transfer-function, homework

Ive currently analysised a circuit and gotten a function
$$(R2 + R1R2Cs)/(R1+R2+sR1R2C)$$
But i need to somehow transform this into the form of $$ H(s) = K * (s+z)/(s+p)$$
where z is a zero and p is a pole.
My circuit has a resistor and capacitor in parallel and another resistor on it own
My working so far is that $$H(s) = Z2/(Z2+Z1)$$
$$Z2 = R2$$
$$Z1 = C1||R1$$
In s domain capacitor is $$1/sC1$$
$$Z1 = 1/(1/R1 + 1/(1/sC1))$$ $$1/((1+sC1R1)/R1)$$
We get: $$Z1 = (1+R1sC1)/R1$$
$$H(s) = R2/[R2 + (1+R1sC1)/R1]$$
Simplifying we get:
$$(R2 + R1R2Cs)/(R1+R2+sR1R2C)$$

[image]

Comment: Please add the homework tag. Show us the working that led to the function you mention in the question.

Comment: The form I recommend is \$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$. Factor some of the terms in the numerator to have 1+... and the same in  the denominator to also have 1+... and you'll have your expression.

Comment: Please don't omit parts of your circuit diagram.

Comment: Your transfer function is wrong, unless you forgot some parenthesis, somewhere.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I dont believe it is incorrect, and if it is why?

Comment: @Mgert33 ,if you really interested in solution ,I would recommend you to make following changes in your question. 1. specify input and output in your circuit because we cannot calculate transfer function until input and output is specified 2.post actual question given in book instead of your version of question

Comment: I see you modified your answer to include the parenthesis that I was hinting at. Now it is correct. If you'll compare the way it was written before the edit, and now, you'll notice that, without the parenthesis, there's a whole different formula. That's why I said it was wrong. As for your question, did you try what @VerbalKint said in his comment?

Comment: So, divide through by R1R2C.